# UWP Grid and/or StackPanel with 50% height

Tags: uwp

I want to arrange 2 Grids (or StackPanels) incl. a Scrollviewer vertical.
Each of them should be 50% of the device's height. Or, to be more precisely: They are in a container and their height should be 50% of the height of that container.
As far as I know I can set the height in Pixels, to "auto" and to "*", but not to percentages.

What technique should be used to reach that goal?

My Code so far:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Pivot Title="Pivot" >
            <PivotItem Header="Start">
                <Grid/>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Baustellenbegehung">
                <Grid/>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Mangelanzeige">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ScrollViewer>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="Aktuelle Mangelanzeigen" />
                                <ListView Name="lstMangelanzeigenAktiv" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ScrollViewer>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="Archiv Mangelanzeigen" />
                                <ListView Name="lstMangelanzeigenArchiv" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Zustandsfeststellungsprotokoll">
                <Grid/>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>

    </Grid>
```

EDIT:

I stripped the code down and added .5* as suggested, but when I fill the ListView I cannot scroll in them:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="Aktuelle Mangelanzeigen" />
                <ListView Name="lstMangelanzeigenAktiv" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Archiv Mangelanzeigen" />
                <ListView Name="lstMangelanzeigenArchiv" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

EDIT 2:
This is a screenshot of my current version.
I added 20 items to both ListViews and I expected to have 2 scrollbars (one per ListView):
[image]

Comment: What kind of container are you using?

Comment: @CiccioRocca: I Pasted it the same time, you asked :)

Comment: I still don't understand very well what should be your desidered result.

Comment: I put a screenshot under "EDIT 2" and hope that it is more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use as container a Grid you can set row definition in percentage:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

It means that the rows occupy 50% of the avaliable height.

EDIT:
According your needs you should solve this way:

```
       <PivotItem Header="Mangelanzeige">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="TB1"/>
                        <ListView Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid >
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"  Text="TB2"/>
                        <ListView Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid >
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
```

In this case using the StackPanel didn't allow you to stretch its content and so, the listview didn't stretch.

Comment: Seems legit, but does not work for me. I copied my stripped down code above - where is my error?

Comment: @StefanMeyer if you change the StackPanel with a Grid it now should work.

Comment: I am missing the scrollbars, but based on your sample I got the missing link and got it running!